# having problem in importing contact from hotmail in php

Tags: php

Im having problem in importing hotmail contacts from hotmail in php it simple give the erorr message : Error code not found

Please tell me what im doing wrong. I want this to be working.

Im using thew msn_contact_grab.class.php
and iam  calling as :

```
<?php
include('msn_contact_grab.class.php');
$msn2 = new msn;
$returned_emails = $msn2->qGrab("just_4_love01@hotmail.com", "xxxxxxx");
?>
```

msn_contact_grab.class.php is as follows:

```
<?php

class msn
{
    var $server =   'messenger.hotmail.com';
    var $port   =   1863;

    var $nexus  =   'https://nexus.passport.com/rdr/pprdr.asp';
    var $ssh_login  =   'login.live.com/login2.srf';

    var $debug  =   0;
    var $curl_bin   =   0;
    var $curl   =   'c:/wamp/www/hotmail/curl/curl';    // linux
    //var $curl =   'c:\curl.exe';      // windows

    //Used to prevent the script from hanging
    var $count = 0;

    //Used to store the email addresses until all have been collected
    var $email_input = array();
    var $email_processing = array();
    var $email_output = array();

    /**
     *
     * desc :   Connect to MSN Messenger Network
     *
     * in   :   $passport   =   passport i.e: user@hotmail.com
     *      $password   =   password for passport
     *
     * out  :   true on success else return false
     *
     */

    function connect($passport, $password)
    {
        $this->trID = 1;

        if (!$this->fp = @fsockopen($this->server, $this->port, $errno, $errstr, 2)) {

            die("Could not connect to messenger service");

        } else {
              stream_set_timeout($this->fp, 2);

            $this->_put("VER $this->trID MSNP9 CVR0\r\n");

            while (! feof($this->fp))
            {
                $data = $this->_get();

                switch ($code = substr($data, 0, 3))
                {
                    default:
                        echo $this->_get_error($code);

                        return false;
                    break;
                    case 'VER':
                        $this->_put("CVR $this->trID 0x0409 win 4.10 i386 MSNMSGR 7.0.0816 MSMSGS $passport\r\n");
                    break;
                    case 'CVR':
                        $this->_put("USR $this->trID TWN I $passport\r\n");
                    break;
                    case 'XFR':
                        list(, , , $ip)  = explode (' ', $data);
                        list($ip, $port) = explode (':', $ip);

                        if ($this->fp = @fsockopen($ip, $port, $errno, $errstr, 2))
                        {
                            $this->trID = 1;

                            $this->_put("VER $this->trID MSNP9 CVR0\r\n");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (! empty($this->debug)) echo 'Unable to connect to msn server (transfer)';

                            return false;
                        }
                    break;
                    case 'USR':
                        if (isset($this->authed))
                        {
                            return true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $this->passport = $passport;
                            $this->password = urlencode($password);

                            list(,,,, $code) = explode(' ', trim($data));

                            if ($auth = $this->_ssl_auth($code))
                            {
                                $this->_put("USR $this->trID TWN S $auth\r\n");

                                $this->authed = 1;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (! empty($this->debug)) echo 'auth failed';

                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

    }

    //Collects the raw data containing the email addresses
    function rx_data()
    {
        $this->_put("SYN $this->trID 0\r\n");

        //Supplies the second MSG code which stops
        //the script from hanging as it waits for
        //more content
        $this->_put("CHG $this->trID NLN\r\n");

        $stream_info = stream_get_meta_data($this->fp);
        $email_total = 100;
        //the count check prevents the script hanging as it waits for more content
        while ((! feof($this->fp)) && (! $stream_info['timed_out']) && ($this->count <= 1) && (count($this->email_input) < $email_total))
        {
            $data = $this->_get();
            $stream_info = stream_get_meta_data($this->fp);

            if ($data)
            {

                switch($code = substr($data, 0, 3))
                {
                    default:
                        // uncommenting this line here would probably give a load of "error code not found" messages.
                        //echo $this->_get_error($code);
                    break;
                    case 'MSG':
                       //This prevents the script hanging as it waits for more content
                       $this->count++;
                    break;
                    case 'LST':
                       //These are the email addresses
                       //They need to be collected in email_input

                       $this->email_input[] = $data;
                       if ($this->debug) print("<span class='b'>" . count($this->email_input) . "</span>");

                    break;
                    case 'SYN':
                    $syn_explode = explode(" ", $data);
                    $email_total = $syn_explode[3];
                    break;
                    case 'CHL':
                        $bits = explode (' ', trim($data));

                        $return = md5($bits[2].'Q1P7W2E4J9R8U3S5');
                        $this->_put("QRY $this->trID msmsgs@msnmsgr.com 32\r\n$return");
                    break;

                }
            }
        }

    }

    //This function extracts the emails and screen names from the raw data 
    //collected by rx_data
    function process_emails () {

      //Neaten up the emails

      //$regex = "|^LST\s(\S+?)\s(\S+?)\s\d+?\s\d+?$|";
      foreach($this->email_input as $email_entry) {

        //Seperate out the email from the name and other data
        $this->email_processing[] = explode(" ", $email_entry);

      }

      //Get rid of the unnecessary data and clean up the name
      foreach($this->email_processing as $email_entry){

        $this->email_output[] = array(0 => $email_entry['1'],
                                        1 => urldecode($email_entry[2]));
    }

    //var_dump($this->email_processing);
    //var_dump($this->email_output);



  }

    //This is a quick way of calling all the seperate functions
    //needed to grab the contact list
    function qGrab ($username, $password) {

      //Connect to the MSNM service
      $this->connect($username, $password);

      //Get data
      $this->rx_data();

      //Process emails
      $this->process_emails();

      //send the email array
      return $this->email_output;


    }


    /*====================================*\
        Various private functions
    \*====================================*/

    function _ssl_auth($auth_string)
    {
        if (empty($this->ssh_login))
        {
            if ($this->curl_bin)
            {
                exec("$this->curl -m 60 -LkI $this->nexus", $header);
                $header = implode($header, null);
            }
            else
            {
                $ch = curl_init($this->nexus);

                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 2);

                $header = curl_exec($ch);

                curl_close($ch);
            }

            preg_match ('/DALogin=(.*?),/', $header, $out);

            if (isset($out[1]))
            {
                $slogin = $out[1];
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $slogin = $this->ssh_login;
        }


        if ($this->curl_bin)
        {
            $header1 = '"Authorization: Passport1.4 OrgVerb=GET,OrgURL=http%3A%2F%2Fmessenger%2Emsn%2Ecom,sign-in='.$this->passport.',pwd='.$this->password.','.$auth_string.'"';

            exec("$this->curl -m 60 -LkI -H $header1 https://$slogin", $auth_string);

            $header = null;

            foreach ($auth_string as $key => $value)
            {
                if (strstr($value, 'Unauthorized'))
                {
                    echo 'Unauthorised';
                    return false;
                }
                elseif (strstr($value, 'Authentication-Info'))
                {
                    $header = $value;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $ch = curl_init('https://'.$slogin);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                            'Authorization: Passport1.4 OrgVerb=GET,OrgURL=http%3A%2F%2Fmessenger%2Emsn%2Ecom,sign-in='.$this->passport.',pwd='.$this->password.','.$auth_string,
                            'Host: login.passport.com'
                            ));

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 2);

            $header = curl_exec($ch);

            curl_close($ch);
        }

        preg_match ("/from-PP='(.*?)'/", $header, $out);

        return (isset($out[1])) ? $out[1] : false;
    }


    function _get()
    {
        if ($data = @fgets($this->fp, 4096))
        {


            if ($this->debug) echo "<div class=\"r\">&lt;&lt;&lt; $data</div>\n";

            return $data;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }


    function _put($data)
    {
        fwrite($this->fp, $data);

        $this->trID++;

        if ($this->debug) echo "<div class=\"g\">&gt;&gt;&gt; $data</div>";
    }


    function _get_error($code)
    {
        switch ($code)
        {
            case 201:
                return 'Error: 201 Invalid parameter';
            break;
            case 217:
                return 'Error: 217 Principal not on-line';
            break;
            case 500:
                return 'Error: 500 Internal server error';
            break;
            case 540:
                return 'Error: 540 Challenge response failed';
            break;
            case 601:
                return 'Error: 601 Server is unavailable';
            break;
            case 710:
                return 'Error: 710 Bad CVR parameters sent';
            break;
            case 713:
                return 'Error: 713 Calling too rapidly';
            break;
            case 731:
                return 'Error: 731 Not expected';
            break;
            case 800:
                return 'Error: 800 Changing too rapidly';
            break;
            case 910:
            case 921:
                return 'Error: 910/921 Server too busy';
            break;
            case 911:
                return 'Error: 911 Authentication failed';
            break;
            case 923:
                return 'Error: 923 Kids Passport without parental consent';
            break;
            case 928:
                return 'Error: 928 Bad ticket';
            break;
            default:
                return 'Error code '.$code.' not found';
            break;
        }
    }




}






?>
```

Comment: please tell me what can i do instead of that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(moving this from a comment to an answer)*

It's probably not that *you* are doing anything wrong, it's probably just that this class is fishy. The `$curl = 'c:/...'; // linux` line doesn't instill a lot of confidence. This also seems to be reverse-engineering the messenger protocol, which is a very fragile thing to do.

There seems to be an official API, which you should be using instead: http://dev.live.com/contacts/